# Declare non-stretching non-pairing delimiters

Tags: math-mode, symbols, delimiters

How do I define my own delimiters from arbitrary symbols for math which have these properties:

- They have a fixed size. Unlike the usual delimiters they do not stretch to adapt to the enclosed content.
- They do not have to be paired. A left delimiter need not be followed by a right delimiter. A right delimiter need not be preceded by a left delimiter.
- Each delimiter can be declared to belong to one of the three sides (left, middle, right).

Example 1: I want to use the $ character as a math delimiter. I want to declare a left, a right, and a middle $ delimiter. I want to be able to use just any one, just any two, or all three variants of $ delimiters.

Example 2: What I want already exists for some characters. There are the `\lvert`and `\rvert` delimiters. I would like to declare delimiting characters of this type for arbitrary characters. So, for my example 1 I would create the new commands `\ldollar`, `\mdollar`, and `\rdollar` which would produce a left, a middle, and a right $ sign delimiter, respectively.

Comment: you can just use `\newcommand to define shortands for `\mathopen{\$}`, `\mathbin{\$}`, `\mathclose{\$}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the commands `\mathopen`, `\mathclose` and `\mathrel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ldollar}{\mathopen{\$}}
\newcommand{\rdollar}{\mathclose{\$}}
\newcommand{\mdollar}{\mathrel{\$}}

\begin{document}
$\log\ldollar a+b\rvert-\{a\mdollar b\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd have guessed \mathbin ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why `\mathbin`? A “middle delimiter” is surely a relation symbol like `\mid`.

Comment: I don't know what `a$b` means but if I had to guess, I'd guess it was semantically closer to `a+b` than `a=b` but who knows:-)